# excel grouping and finding maximum value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the maximum values in the days column for each time slot with different Product ID.
Product ID  Time slot   Days                **My expected Result**
2101            1   20
2101            1   21              Product ID  Time Slot   Max Days
2101            2   14              2101               1    21
2101            2   19              2101               2    19
2102            1   17
2102            2   25
2102            1   16              2102               1    26
2102            2   20              2102               2    25
2102            2   11
2102            1   26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way may be a PivotTable with `Product ID` for ROWS, `Time slot` for COLUMNS and Max of `Days` for VALUES.

Comment: i need answers other than doing Pivot

Comment: any formula is there?